# "Making a difference" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, idioms

What does the phrase "making a difference" mean?e.g. 
Making a difference:philanthropy and volunteerism in America.

What does this sentence mean?
Is it asking about the difference between philanthropy and volunteerism or any other thing?

I think it does not mean the difference between philanthropy and volunteerism but I am confused if it doesn't mean this then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *make a difference* in any endeavour or field means, broadly, to have a significant effect.

Until recently the expression was usually encountered as *make **the** difference*, typically the difference between a positive outcome and a flat or negative outcome. For instance, we might say that a star sales manager “made the difference” between her company breaking even and turning a very nice profit.

In the last ten or fifteen years or so, however, the expression has been most often used in exhortations to “make **a** difference” in your community: to give generously not just of your money but of your time and your expertise to make your community a better place for everyone. Companies proclaim that they want to “make a difference” by supporting local charities, or by providing advice to start-up businesses or by training displaced workers in new job skills. And the rising Millenial generation of young people is popularly supposed to have a more earnest desire to “make a difference” than their self- and family-centered parents and grandparents.

Answer (score 1):

"Making a difference" means causing change (generally positive change) in a community, in this case by way of volunteering.